# UIVideoEditorController breaks MPMoviePlayerViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, I can use code like this to play a video:

```
- (void)playVideo:(NSURL *)url {
    MPMoviePlayerViewController *m = [[[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:url] autorelease];
    [self.rootViewController presentMoviePlayerViewControllerAnimated:m];
}
```

And it works fine.

But if I use code like this to display a video editor:

```
- (void)editVideo:(NSString *)file {
    UIVideoEditorController *ed = [[[UIVideoEditorController alloc] init] autorelease];
    ed.delegate = self;
    ed.videoPath = file;
    [self.rootViewController presentModalViewController:ed animated:YES];
}

- (void)videoEditorControllerDidCancel:(UIVideoEditorController *)vc {
    [vc.parentViewController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

and just hit cancel, the `playVideo:` method will no longer play a video! It brings up the movie player window fine and does the throbber to indicate loading, but once the load finishes it fails. Sometimes it closes the video window right away without playing anything, and sometimes it changes to a black screen that responds to no input (but will go away if I send the app to the background and then bring it back to the foreground). It's not [MPMoviePlayerViewController Black Screen issue!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231033/mpmovieplayerviewcontroller-black-screen-issue) though, as I get the same black screen if I intentionally leak the MPMoviePlayerViewController.

Am I doing something wrong, or is Apple's junk just broken?

Comment: I see the same problem. Setting the contentURL of the MPMoviePlayerViewController when the UIVideoEditorController is dismissed does not seem to work either.

Comment: Actually my issue was different because I had a MPMoviePlayerViewController with its view installed in my current view. When I brought up the UIVideoEditorController to edit the video and it was dismissed the MPMoviePlayerViewController view would be blank. The workaround was to set the contentURL of the MPMoviePlayerViewController to nil before showing the UIVideoEditorController. Then when the UIVideoEditorController was done I could set the contentURL back to the old value, but only after a slight delay.